# Equivalence in circuits

Tags: circuit-analysis, current-source, short-circuit, linear, resistive

I'm studying circuit theory, with only linear elements and no capacitors or inductors or mutual inductances, so no differential equations. All the sources (current and voltages) are constant.

- To be even more precise, that means that resistors, ideal current/voltage sources, dependent current/voltage sources, op-amps, ideal transformers are all and the only elements allowed.

**QUESTION**

My question is: is it always true that, if we have to find a current/voltage in B, which is a circuit with whatever inside it (but that must satisfy the premises said before), thanks to the short circuit we can solve the circuit as if there was no ideal current source (the one on the left)?
In other words, are the two circuits below equivalent, if my goal is to find a current/voltage in B?
[image: given circuit]

**FURTHER CLARIFICATIONS/MORE CONTEXT**

The question originated from a exercise done by my professor: given the circuit on the left we need to find the voltage i_x and he did that by simply ignoring the current source, so it means that current source in parallel with short circuit is equivalent to the short circuit.

[image]

Comment: It's not entirely clear to me, your question. But in general given your set up (no capacitors and no inductors, etc) a black box **B** with just two terminals, the current entering one terminal will equal the current exiting the other terminal. (Must be the case.) All the remaining nodes Inside the black box must obey KCL (zero sum.) You can measure the voltage between the terminals, you can inject a current and measure the voltage between the terminals again, you can apply a voltage to the terminals and measure the current, etc. But I just don't know if that helps any.

Comment: @periblepsis thanks, I think I made my question less confusing by adding the specific exercise that made the question come to my mind

Comment: Yes, putting a current source across a dead short doesn't impact anything except for the short's current magnitude. The current source just applies its current to the short, adding its current to whatever else may be using the short. It's not clear to me what \$v_x\$ is. I can see a \$v_s\$ and \$i_x\$. But not \$v_x\$.

Comment: @periblepsis thank you very much (v_x instead of i_x was just a typo, I just corrected it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost. Circuit B can be analyzed as drawn. There is still a current source. I would draw it this way. The diagram demonstrates more completely.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fpYY2V.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

**Update** Yes you are correct. The currrent \$i_x\$ depends only on on the elements inside the box and the short. The short makes \$R_2||R_3\$.

All of \$I_S\$ flows through the short also, but has no effect inside the box.

Comment: sorry, I didn't really get your answer. Which of the two circuits should I look at?